# Image element doesn't update when the image content changes with QDeclarativeImageProvider

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a listview element like this :

```
ListView {
    id: view
    width: 200; height: 250
    model:myModel;
    delegate:
        Text{
            text:  bareJid + ' '+status;
            Image{
                source:image;
            }
        }
}
```

in the delegate Image element gets its image from a [QDeclarativeImageProvider](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html) . but when the content of the image changes myModel doesn't update. How can I notice it to reload image when the content of the image has changed.
thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the answer is already in your question - `myModel` should emit `dataChanged` signal when actual data (your image) changes.

Comment: If you want the image to be change when the contents of the image is changed, the you have to use QFileSystemWatcher - http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfilesystemwatcher.html I think.Otherwise you have to change the source of the Image explicitly whenever someone changes the image contents. Probably the better way could be what Martin suggested.

Comment: Yes its to late :) but future reference for needy : https://forum.qt.io/topic/6935/how-to-reload-an-image-in-qml/19 ,, Random number can add with prefix of "?" to source property of image control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Image item will not attempt to re-fetch the image at all unless the source is changed.  Typically this is achieved by appending an id, which you can increment, to the end of the image name and dealing with that in your model and provider.  You should also set `cache: false` since there is no point caching an image that is changing.

Another possibility may be to set `cache: false` and change the image role first to "", and then back to the actual name, remembering to emit dataChanged after each change.  Note that the image must not have previously been loaded with cache: true, or the cached version will be used regardless (this is fixed in QtQuick 2.0).

Comment: Thanks for the tip with setting the image to an empty value and then to the provider again, this is a reliable way of forcing a redraw